# Непонятная часть кода

Tags: java

Увидел задачу, суть которой была переопределить методы equals и hashcode чтобы сравнение объектов работало правильно. Так вот, что значит эта строка?

> ```
> if (first != null ? !first.equals(solution.first) : solution.first != null)
>         return false;
> ```

```
public class Solution {
private final String first, last;

public Solution(String first, String last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    Solution solution = (Solution) o;

    if (first != null ? !first.equals(solution.first) : solution.first != null)
        return false;
    if (last != null ? !last.equals(solution.last) : solution.last != null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = first != null ? first.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (last != null ? last.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Solution> s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(new Solution("Mickey", "Mouse"));
    System.out.println(s.contains(new Solution("Mickey", "Mouse")));
}
}
```

Comment: Это тернарный эквивалент `first != null && !first.equals(solution.first) || first == null && solution.first != null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тернарный оператор, как аргумент условного оператора - довольно забавно.

Вся строка эквивалентна классической записи:

```
if (first != null) {if (!first.equals(solution.first) return false;}
 else {if (solution.first != null) return false;}
```

Тернарный оператор вида `(условие)? оператор1: оператор2;` проверяет условие перед знаком вопроса и если оно истинно - выполняется `оператор1` иначе выполняется `оператор2`. В данном конкретном коде подставляется одно из условий проверки в условный оператор `if`, в зависимости от того равно `first` null или нет.

если `first = !null` будет сформирован оператор:

```
if (!first.equals(solution.first) return false;
```

иначе, если `first == null`, будет сформирован оператор:

```
if (solution.first != null) return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Это тернарный оператор

```
(условие)?(вернуть это если условие верно):(вернуть это если условие не верно)
```

Пример

```
int x = 42;
int i = x == 42 ? 42 : -1; //в итоге i присваивается 42
```